# how to combine seperate date and time as inputs to get them as together?

Tags: php, html

I have two date fields and two time fields as input from html form and wanted to combine these seperate dates and times together so that  i can fetch all the values from the database table using mysql query.
like if fromdate:2014-5-6  todate:2014-5-7
        fromtime:14:8      totime:15:5
ans should be select * from tablename where data between these two dates and times is fetched as result.
following is my code..plz tell me where im going wrong..plz help me..thanks in advc
project.html

```html
<b>From Date:</b>
<input type="text" id="fromdate" name="fromdate" size="20" />
<b>To Date:</b>
<input type="text" id="todate" name="todate" size="20"/><br><br>
<b>From Time:</b>
<input type="text" id="fromtime" name="fromtime" size="30" />
<b>To Time:</b>
<input type="text" id="totime" name="totime" size="30"/><br><br>
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="GENERATE"/><br><br>

project.php

  $from_date_and_time=null;
   $frdttm=null;
   $to_date_and_time=null;
   $todttm=null;
 if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
 {
    $fromdate=$_POST['fromdate'];
 $todate=$_POST['todate'];
 $fromtime=$_POST['fromtime'];
 $totime=$_POST['totime'];
 
   $from_date_and_time=$fromdate .'  '. $fromtime;
      $frdttm=strtotime("$from_date_and_time");
      $to_date_and_time=$todate .'  '. $totime;
      $todttm=strtotime("$to_date_and_time");
 $hours = 24;
     // Check if date is more recent than the specified number of hours
      if ((time() - $frdttm) < (60 * 60 * $hours))
       {
         echo 'Yes!';
       }
     if ((time() - $todttm) < (60 * 60 * $hours))
       {
         echo 'Yes!';
       }
 
 if(!$fromdate || !$todate ||!$fromtime||!$totime)
 echo " please provide all the fields";  
    $pk=@mysql_connect("localhost", "root" ,"")or die ("cannot open");
    if(!$pk)
 echo "fail";
 
    $db=@mysql_select_db("test",$pk);

     if(!$db)
  echo "<br>database not selected";
 
  else
  {
   $query = "SELECT * FROM floattable WHERE (DateAndTime between '$frdttm' AND '$todttm') ORDER BY DateAndTime ASC;";
   echo "Connected";
   echo "<br>";
   $result=mysql_query($query);
   echo "result";
   echo"<br>";
   if($result)
   echo $result;
   $numrows=mysql_num_rows($result);
   echo $numrows;
$i=0;
echo"<table border='1' cellspacing='3' align=left>
<tr>
<th>DateAndTime</th>
<th>MillItm</th>
<th>TagIndex</th>
<th>Value</th>
<th>Status</th>
<th>Marker</th>
</tr>";
while($i<$numrows)
 {
 echo"<tr>";
 echo "<td>".mysql_result($result,$i,'DateAndTime')."</td>";
 echo "<td>".mysql_result($result,$i,'Millitm')."</td>";
 echo "<td>".mysql_result($result,$i,'TagIndex')."</td>";
 echo "<td>".mysql_result($result,$i,'Value')."</td>";
 echo "<td>".mysql_result($result,$i,'Status')."</td>";
 echo "<td>".mysql_result($result,$i,'Marker')."</td>";
 echo"</tr>";
 $i++;
 }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to give name as a Array which you want to Merge together Like :

```
<b>From Date:</b>
<input type="text" id="fromdatetime[]" name="fromdate" size="20" />
<b>To Date:</b>
<input type="text" id="todatetime[]" name="todate" size="20"/><br><br>
<b>From Time:</b>
<input type="text" id="fromdatetime[]" name="fromtime" size="30" />
<b>To Time:</b>
<input type="text" id="todatetime[]" name="totime" size="30"/><br><br>
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="GENERATE"/><br><br>
```

After that you can get value as a array in action page and then you can merge array in String by using **implode** function like:

```
$fromArr = $_POST['fromdatetime'];
implode('-',$fromArr);
```